# Index error while using Sieve of Eratosthenes in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

When trying to find prime numbers using Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm, following code is used. It gives index error when executed.

I cannot find why the index is out of range.
I am using Python 2.7

```
"""
This program will find all the prime numbers up to the entered number using Sieve of Eratosthenes Algorithm
"""

while True:
    print "\n" * 3
    list1 = []
    final = []
    max = raw_input("Enter number upto which you want to find prime numbers or enter 0 to exit :")
    if max.isdigit():
        d = int(max)
        for i in range (2,d):
            list1.append(i)
        print list1

        k = 0
        x = 0

        while True:
            temp = list1[k]
            final.append(temp)
            length = len(list1)

            if (k+1) != length:
                for x in range(k+1,length):
                    temp1 = list1[x]
                    temp2 = final[k]
                    if temp1 % temp2 == 0:
                        del list1[x]  
                k += 1
            else:
                break

        print(final)

    else:
        print ("Invalid Input...!!")
        continue
```

Comment: Where in your code does the `IndexError` occur?

Comment: It shows the error on: "temp1 = list1[x]"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is the line `del list1[x]`. After the interpreter entered that line the first time, it is inevitable that an IndexError occurs, since `length - 1` (the upper limit of `x` in your for-loop) now is larger than the last index of `list1`

Two possible solutions:

1. Capture the `IndexError` and `break` the for loop then
2. Use a while-loop like this

   ```
   if (k+1) != length:
       x = k+1
       while x < len(list1):
           temp1 = list1[x]
           temp2 = final[k]
           if temp1 % temp2 == 0:
               del list1[x]
           x += 1
       k += 1
   else:
       break
   ```

Comment: Yes, it Worked..!! 

Thank You...!!

Answer (score 1):

You're deleting elements from the list, which is making the list shorter (hence, elements that were initially fine to check will be out of range. That is, once you delete 4, you'll find an error when you look for the 5th element. A way to verify this is to throw an

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

in your code and print out list1 each time. You can use `c` to move forward to the next loop iteration.

A solution is to copy list1 to a list named `primes` to start, and then delete elements from `primes` rather than `list1`.

Comment: When the input is less than or equal to 5, it is working correctly, when input number is more than 5, it shows error.

Comment: I edited my answer to clarify. Your loop _should_ break once you hit 5, because 4 is the first number you delete.

Comment: Yes, got it...!! Once a number is deleted, the range of list will change and next index will be unavailable.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. Don't forget to mark the question as resolved!